# 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to execute the following code and am receiving an error

```
public List<Log> GetLoggingData(DateTime LogDate, string title)
{
     var context = new LoggingEntities();
     var query = from t in context.Logs

           where t.Title == title 
           && t.Timestamp == LogDate

           select t;
     return query.ToList();
}
```

The error I'm receiving is "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."  I have tried various attempts of casting everythign to a string, only comparing the date part, but can't seem to get the right combinaation.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us the Logs class and the table it's being mapped to.

Comment: I am using EFv1 with .net 3.5.
The log class is just a log table from the enterprise library with the title as a String type and Timestamp as a datetime field.  I just want to compare the datepart

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not the greatest solution, but it works.  For a variety of reasons, I have to use .net 3.5 at this point and modifying the database would be difficult.  Anyways, here is a solution that works:

```
            var query = from t in context.Logs
                      where t.Title == title 
                      && t.Timestamp.Day == LogDate.Day
                      && t.Timestamp.Month == LogDate.Month
                      && t.Timestamp.Year == LogDate.Year
                      select t;
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it is effective.

Comment: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 90):

If you are using EF 6.0+, you can use [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime?)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D)) :

```
var query =
    from t in context.Logs
    where t.Title == title 
    && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.Timestamp) == LogDate.Date
    select t;
```

> Note: For earlier version of EF where `DbFunctions` isn't available, [`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime?)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) can be used instead.

Comment: You will also have to Truncate your LogDate.Date property

Comment: @invalidusername LogDate is a DateTime which means that LogDate.Date is "truncated"

Comment: +1 for you sir. I couldn't use the accepted answer in my case as I did a 'greater than' comparison, in which you can't compare on Day, Month and Year separately.

Comment: Didn't know about the functions. Fantastic.

Comment: BTW -- That function is now obsolete and has been moved to another assembly.  Use 'DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.Timestamp)' instead.

Comment: Make sure to put your date in a variable. I did a compare like 'DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.Timestamp) == DateTime.Now.Date', but that doesn't work. 'var today = DateTime.Now.Date; DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.Timestamp) == today works!

Answer (score 3):

[EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(t.Timestamp)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd395596%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is obsolete from EF6.

Use below

[DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.Timestamp)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Always use EntityFunctions.TruncateTime() for  both x.DateTimeStart and LogDate.
such as :

```
var query = from t in context.Logs
              where t.Title == title 
              && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(t.Timestamp) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(LogDate)
              select t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but in mikemurf22's example, it would need to check each part of the date component, and potentially a lot more server processing?

Anyway, I stumbled across this problem, and this is my solution.

Assuming that you're going to be passing in the date component only, you can find the last minute of the day that you pass in, and use the where clause to define the range.

```
public List<Log> GetLoggingData(DateTime LogDate, string title)
{
    DateTime enddate = new DateTime(LogDate.Year, LogDate.Month, LogDate.Day, 23, 59, 59)

    var query = from t in context.Logs
                where t.Timestamp >= date
                where t.Timestamp <= enddate
                select t;

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert LongDate to `.ToShortDateString`and then you can use it this way:

```
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(t.Timestamp) == LogDate
```

like mike did

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var calDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-90);

var result = return (from r in xyz where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(r.savedDate) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(calDate)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this hack:

```
DateTime startDate = LogDate.Date;
DateTime endDate = LogDate.Date.AddDays(1);

var query = from t in context.Logs
            where t.Title == title 
                  && t.Timestamp >= startDate 
                  && t.Timestamp < endDate
            select t;
```

Comment: I corrected it a little. Of cource you can't use AddDays method inside your query. But you can move it outside. So workaround still works.