# How to use MySQL function 'Date' in EF Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I want to **group by Date of datetime cloumn**(eg.CreateTime ='20017-01-01 01:01:01') to use `Sum` aggregate functions.

- EntityFramework 6 Code first
- NetFramework 4.5
- MYSQL Server 6.9.9

  ```
   var myData = from certifiedRecord in DbSet
          join shopInfo in DbContext.ShopInfos
          on certifiedRecord.ShopId equals shopInfo.ID into joinedCertify
          from shopCertifiedRecord in joinedCertify
          group shopCertifiedRecord
          by EntityFunctions.Date(certifiedRecord.CreateTime)
          into g
          orderby g.Key
          select new ShopCertifiedDayInfoResponse
          {
              Day = g.Key.Value,
              NormalCount = g.Sum(t => t.CertifiedType.CompareTo(1)),
              VipCount = g.Sum(t => t.CertifiedType.CompareTo(2))
          };
  ```

But there is not `EntityFunctions.Date` function for EF with Mysql.

[image]

Is there a way to solve the problem?

Now I just use the CustomQuery to solve the Problem.

I Just want to know how to use `EntityFunctions`(maybe another thins) to solve the Problem.In another way, I want to using Linq for EF to solve the problem.

Comment: There is a DateTime.Parse(string) that will convert a string date to a DateTime object.

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11754787/6741868) you could either use [DbFunctions.TruncateTime Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D)) (EF 6.0+) or [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime Method (Nullable<DateTime>)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) for earlier versions of EF.

Comment: I want to `Group By ` a date extract from  DateTime Column(eg. CreateTime),so I need to use 'Date' function (Mysql function).

Comment: @KeyurPATEL it's not working for me

Comment: Which one did you try? (based on your EF version), and also what error does it give. It would be great if you posted the code you tried.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL `FUNCTION xxxxxdb.TruncateTime does not exist` the EF throw the error. tow function I have tried, but all failed.

Comment: Why the "xxxxxdb"? Based on your version, it will either be `by System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime(certifiedRecord.CreateTime)` or `by System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(certifiedRecord.CreateTime)`. I still don't know your EF version.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL EF 6.1.3, `xxxxxdb` is my DB name

Comment: @KeyurPATEL `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` works in SQLServer but not in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It is a hacky solution (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19731414/6741868) as well), but you could just create the function in your database:

```
Create FUNCTION TruncateTime(dateValue DateTime) RETURNS date
return Date(dateValue);
```

And after that your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that I solved by putting .ToList() right before I got the date. Some methods can't operate on unexecuted queries, so materializing the list beforehand could solve the problem.